# I'm trying to make a game similar to Zork but something's wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. This is the third coding language I've learned, so maybe it's a syntax error? This is just the moving section:

I'm trying to get it to change *currentposition* when you move, then tell you where you moved to. Instead it kept saying "Sorry, this space does not exist" no matter what.

```
possibleplace = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
currentposition = 11

def movenorth(currentposition):
    ismovingnorthpossible = (currentposition - 10) in possibleplace
    if ismovingnorthpossible:
        currentposition = currentposition - 10
        return "You have moved North"
    else:
        return "Sorry, this space does not exist."
def moveeast(currentposition):
    ismovingeastpossible = (currentposition + 1) in possibleplace
    if ismovingeastpossible:
        currentposition = currentposition + 1
        return "You have moved East"
    else:
        return "Sorry, this space does not exist."
def movewest(currentposition):
    ismovingwestpossible = (currentposition - 1) in possibleplace
    if ismovingwestpossible:
        currentposition = currentposition - 1
        return "You have moved West"
    else:
        return "Sorry, this space does not exist."

def movesouth(currentposition):
    ismovingsouthpossible = (currentposition + 10) in possibleplace
    if ismovingsouthpossible:
        oldposition = currentposition
        currentposition = oldposition + 10
        return "You have moved South"
    else:
        return "Sorry, this space does not exist."


action = input("Type s, south, or go south to move south, etc. (you get 1000 moves!)  ")

if action.lower() == 'north' or action.lower() == 'n' or action.lower() == "move north":
    currentposition = movenorth(currentposition)
    print(currentposition)
numofturnsleft = 1000

while numofturnsleft > 0:
    action = input("")
    numofturnsleft -= 1
    print(numofturnsleft)

    
    print(movenorth(currentposition))
if action.lower() == 'south' or action.lower() == 's' or action.lower() == "move south":
    currentposition = movesouth(currentposition)
    print(currentposition)
    print(movesouth(currentposition))
if  action.lower() == 'west' or action.lower() == 'w' or action.lower() == "move west":
    currentposition = movewest(currentposition)
    print(currentposition)
    print(movewest(currentposition))
if  action.lower() == 'east' or action.lower() == 'e' or action.lower() == "move east":
    currentposition = moveeast(currentposition)
    print(currentposition)
    print(moveeast(currentposition))
```

Comment: `currentposition = movenorth(currentposition)` - this is wrong.  `movenorth` (and the rest) return a string, so `currentposition` will be overwritten with the wrong type.

Comment: Setting the function parameter `currentposition` does not affect the variable `currentposition` used as an argument to the function.